# How to use Sum SQL with Spring Data MongoDB?

Tags: java, spring-data, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb

I want to sum the values of a column `price.value` where the column `validatedAt` is between `startDate` and `endDate`.
So I want a `BigInteger` as a result (the sum value).
This is what I tried:

```
        final List<AggregationOperation> aggregationOperations = new ArrayList<>();
        aggregationOperations.add(Aggregation.match(where("validatedAt").gte(startDate).lt(endDate)));
        aggregationOperations.add(Aggregation.group().sum("price.value").as("total"));

        final Aggregation turnoverAggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(OrderEntity.class, aggregationOperations);

        return this.mongoOperations.aggregate(turnoverAggregation, OrderEntity.class, BigInteger.class).getUniqueMappedResult();
```

This doesn't work. I have this error:

```
{"exception":"com.application.CommonClient$Builder$6","path":"/api/stats/dashboard","message":"Failed to instantiate java.math.BigInteger using constructor NO_CONSTRUCTOR with arguments ","error":"Internal Server Error","timestamp":1493209463953,"status":500}
```

Any help?

Comment: Have you tried using a Long? I'm not sure why you expect a BigInteger

Comment: The error makes sense if you look at the BigInteger JavaDoc. The isn't a constructor with no arguments

Comment: Long does not work. What should I put then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don`t need to add a new pojo for just for this. It is helpful when you more fields to map and you want spring to map them automatically.

The correct way to fix the problem is to use `BasicDBObject` because MongoDB stores all values as key value pairs.

```
return this.mongoOperations.aggregate(turnoverAggregation, OrderEntity.class, BasicDBObject.class).getUniqueMappedResult().getInt("total");
```

Sidenote: You should use Double/BigDecimal for monetary values.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this problem by creating a class that has a BigInteger attribute:

```
private class Total {
    private int total;
}

 return this.mongoOperations.aggregate(turnoverAggregation, OrderEntity.class, Total.class).getUniqueMappedResult();
```

Comment: That is a regular `int`, not `BigInteger`.